# Android: animate he images towards center and expand

Tags: android, animation

I have 3 images in a horizantal layout

[image1] [image2] [image3]

If I click on any one of the image, say for example [image3], both image1 and image2 should animate towards the center setting image3 in the center

```
     [image3]
```

when I click on image3 it animates with 3 images like

[image1] [image3] [image2]

center of the image indicates which image was selected

I need help on creating this scenario in android

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario - [Adding Animations](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html) or [Tutorial of Move Animation](http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2013/06/how-to-move-an-image-from-left-to-right-and-right-to-left-in-android.html)

Comment: @user3722531 no. The links that provided to you is what you need.